# How to reduce/aggregate a list of dicts per multiple keys in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dicts like this:

```
sales_per_store_per_day = [
   {'date':'2014-06-01', 'store':'a', 'product1':10, 'product2':3, 'product3':15},
   {'date':'2014-06-01', 'store':'b', 'product1':20, 'product2':4, 'product3':16},
   {'date':'2014-06-02', 'store':'a', 'product1':30, 'product2':5, 'product3':17},
   {'date':'2014-06-02', 'store':'b', 'product1':40, 'product2':6, 'product3':18},
]
```

How could I reduce this list to have a sum of products for each store, ignoring the date? The result for the above input would be:

```
sales_per_store = [
   {'store':'a', 'product1':40, 'product2':8, 'product3':32},
   {'store':'b', 'product1':60, 'product2':10, 'product3':34}
]
```

Comment: How do you think? What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? Why not make `sales_per_store` a dictionary of dictionaries `{store: {product: count, ...}, ...}`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to track info per store, and [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to ease summing of the numbers:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

by_store = defaultdict(Counter)

for info in sales_per_store_per_day:
    counts = Counter({k: v for k, v in info.items() if k not in ('store', 'date')})
    by_store[info['store']] += counts

sales_per_store = [dict(v, store=k) for k, v in by_store.items()]
```

`counts` is a `Counter()` instance built from each of the products in the `info` dictionary; I'm assuming that everything except the `store` and `date` keys are product counts. It uses a dict comprehension to produce a copy with those two keys removed. The `by_store[info['store']]` looks up the current total counts for the given store (which default to a new, empty `Counter()` object).

The last line then produces your desired output; new dictionaries with `'store'` and per-product counts, but you may want to just keep the dictionary mapping from store to `Counter` objects.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict, Counter
>>> sales_per_store_per_day = [
...    {'date':'2014-06-01', 'store':'a', 'product1':10, 'product2':3, 'product3':15},
...    {'date':'2014-06-01', 'store':'b', 'product1':20, 'product2':4, 'product3':16},
...    {'date':'2014-06-02', 'store':'a', 'product1':30, 'product2':5, 'product3':17},
...    {'date':'2014-06-02', 'store':'b', 'product1':40, 'product2':6, 'product3':18},
... ]
>>> by_store = defaultdict(Counter)
>>> for info in sales_per_store_per_day:
...     counts = Counter({k: v for k, v in info.items() if k not in ('store', 'date')})
...     by_store[info['store']] += counts
... 
>>> [dict(v, store=k) for k, v in by_store.items()]
[{'store': 'a', 'product3': 32, 'product2': 8, 'product1': 40}, {'store': 'b', 'product3': 34, 'product2': 10, 'product1': 60}]
```

Comment: Martijn...that's an elegant solution. Nice. Would it be possible to edit to include a bit of _basics_ discussion of what is actually happening on the two lines inside of the `for info in sales...` loop?  ...for general-educations-sake?

Answer (score 2):

Version without `collections` - maybe more readable for begginers.

```
sales_per_store_per_day = [
   {'date':'2014-06-01', 'store':'a', 'product1':10, 'product2':3, 'product3':15},
   {'date':'2014-06-01', 'store':'b', 'product1':20, 'product2':4, 'product3':16},
   {'date':'2014-06-02', 'store':'a', 'product1':30, 'product2':5, 'product3':17},
   {'date':'2014-06-02', 'store':'b', 'product1':40, 'product2':6, 'product3':18},
]

results = {}

for x in sales_per_store_per_day:

    # default value
    if x['store'] not in results:
        results[x['store']] = {'store': x['store'], 'product1':0, 'product2':0, 'product3':0}

    results[x['store']]['product1'] += x['product1']
    results[x['store']]['product2'] += x['product2']
    results[x['store']]['product3'] += x['product3']

print results

sales_per_store = results.values()

print sales_per_store
```

.

```
# results
{
  'a': {'product3': 32, 'product1': 40, 'store': 'a', 'product2': 8}, 
  'b': {'product3': 34, 'product1': 60, 'store': 'b', 'product2': 10}
}

# sales_per_store
[
  {'product3': 32, 'product1': 40, 'store': 'a', 'product2': 8}, 
  {'product3': 34, 'product1': 60, 'store': 'b', 'product2': 10}
]
```