# How to aggregate dataset by multiple keys in python?

Tags: python, django, sum, dataset, aggregation

I want to summarize dataset, having combined unique key
(in example - (track, singer).

For example: I have dataset with 3 fields: track, singer, cnt
I want to aggregate (summarize) data by track & singer, summzrizing cnt field.

```
sales = [
    {'singer': 'Smash',  'track':  'Cry', 'cnt': 10},
    {'singer': 'Smash',  'track':  'Cry', 'cnt': 11},
    {'singer': 'Smash',  'track':  'Dry', 'cnt': 2},
    {'singer': 'Scooter', 'track': 'Shy', 'cnt': 1},
    {'singer': 'Scooter', 'track': 'Die', 'cnt': 0},
]
```

I want have:

```
sales = [
    {'singer': 'Smash',  'track':  'Cry', 'cnt': 21},   <== summmarized
    {'singer': 'Smash',  'track':  'Dry', 'cnt': 2},
    {'singer': 'Scooter', 'track': 'Shy', 'cnt': 1},
    {'singer': 'Scooter', 'track': 'Die', 'cnt': 0},
]
```

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically looking for the `Sum` of `cnt` grouped by `singer` and `track`. In Django this can be achieved using `values` and `annotate` [in conjunction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#values).

So try something like this:

```
Sale.objects.values('singer', 'track').annotate(Sum('cnt'))
```

Comment: Thanks, but as you can see I operate with dataset, not objects; than, how to convert my dataset to objects to use your func?

Comment: Ah I didn't notice, well then `Django` can't help you here, you need to do it yourself and as far as I can see you have managed to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Created my own solution:

```
# Aggregate dataset by multiple columns
# @source http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24286933/how-to-reduce-aggregate-a-list-of-dicts-per-multiple-keys-in-python
sales = [
    {'singer': 'Smash',   'track':  'Cry', 'cnt': 10},
    {'singer': 'Smash',   'track':  'Cry', 'cnt': 11},
    {'singer': 'Smash',   'track':  'Dry', 'cnt': 2},
    {'singer': 'Scooter', 'track':  'Shy', 'cnt': 1},
    {'singer': 'Scooter', 'track':  'Die', 'cnt': 0},
]

sales_gr = {}

for item in sales:

    key = str(''.join([item['track'], item['singer']]))
    if key not in sales_gr:
        sales_gr[key] = {'track': item['track'], 'singer':item['singer'], 'cnt':0}

    sales_gr[key]['cnt'] += item['cnt']

print(sales_gr)
```